# I am unable to install any program in ubuntu 14.04. What should I do?

Tags: software-installation

i had tried to install vlc, wine, etc. on my newly installed ubuntu 14.04 but nothing is being installed. The message appears that :-
Package dependicies cannot be resolved.
please help me.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message.

Comment: How did you try it? Do you use `sudo apt-get install <package>` in the terminal? If so, can you produce the output error please?

Comment: Add the full error messages to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have broken packages. Please try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

First line makes sure you have updated sources for your packages.
Second line attempts to correct a system with broken dependencies in place (from apt-get help).

Comment: User may also want to try " sudo dpkg --configure -a" To fix broken packages before running updates.

Comment: Guys, when you do edits on posts and then revert or change them, make sure you are not making it incorrect ...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands:

```
 # apt-get install -y aptitude
 # aptitude search vlc         ( this will search the exact vlc_pakg_name)
 # aptitude install -y vlc_pakg_name
 # aptitude search wine         ( this will search the exact wine_pakg_name)
 # aptitude install -y wine_pakg_name
```

Either run as root or use sudo